# Visual studio 2017 switching monitors when I dock my computer to different docking stations

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, docking

This seems to be a brand new issue that never happened to me until VS 2017.  I alternate working from home and the office, and I have the exact same model docking port for my laptop in both places.  I have the exact same monitor layout, Windows 7.  Whenever I dock at home, the main window appears on the right-hand monitor instead of the left where it was when I undocked at the office:

[image]

This is how it looked when I left the office:

[image]

If I switch it back to "normal" at home, then it's swapped when I dock at the office.  So I'm constantly switching it back to "normal" each time I change locations.

Like I said, this just started happening in VS 2017.  I've used VS 2008, 2010, and 2013 with this setup.  **Is there a setting that's different in 2017?**  [Google's no help](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=Visual+studio+2017+switching+monitors+when+I+dock+my+computer+to+different+docking+stations).

Comment: Are both your computers configured with the primary monitor (set from windows control panel) in the same orientation?

Comment: @BradleyUffner -- It's only one computer.  Same computer, two locations.

Comment: They're two different monitors, though, and Windows detects them differently. Still check the Display control panel to see how they're arranged.